# create a project from a template

Tags: templates, project, code-generation

I have several project setups in very different languages. For example an android project.
Whenever I want to create a new android project I copy that project, rename everything I need to rename and I have a ready to go project with which I start working.

Since this is very time consuming and I am sure this can be automated I thought about creating a tool that does this for me, but then I thought there are probably thousand solutions out there, which solve the exact same problem already, I am just not aware of.

So my question is, do you know of any tools like this? The requirements I see are, that it has to be os, language, IDE independent and it must support a command line interface. Ideally with less setup effort.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Telosys (https://www.telosys.org) a lightweight code generator that is able to generate any kind of langage with any kind of framework.
This tool is quite simple, free and Open Source.
It provides a Command Line Interface (so it can be used with any environment/IDE).

It is usualy used to boostrap a project and to generated all the repetitive code (CRUD, Controllers, unit tests, HTML pages, etc)

See also :

- https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/
- https://www.slideshare.net/lguerin/telosys-project-booster-paris-open-source-summit-2019

Comment: Yes, Telosys is great for project bootstrapping (whatever the language or framework)

Comment: It's very close to what I had in mind. The disadvantage I see, is that I need to create template files using this `${var}` notation in *.vm files. This in general is fine, but this makes it hard to maintain the templates. I cannot simply have a working project running, which is supposed to be my template.